# Sticky footer issues in IE - using wordpress

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sticky-footer

I've modified a wordpress template so that, among other things, it has a sticky footer that gets pushed down when the screen fills with content.  Everything is working beautifully in non-IE browsers, but something's horribly wrong in IE.  The footer's sticky, alright, but doesn't push down.  Bonus points: The header, In IE, also appears to be off.  Could be related...

site: http://www.hospiceball.com/wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is rendering in Quirks Mode on IE8. When I forced the browser to render in standards mode, the effect you desire was achieved. When I viewed the source, you have a

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

preceding your DOCTYPE declaration. That is what is causing the Quirks Mode to engage.

Comment: thanks, I figured it was something outside of what I was looking into.